# CAS 5.2.0-RC3 Rest Password Management Webflow

Tags: cas

I'm using CAS 5.2.0-RC3 to authenticate users (using a REST authentication provider). Right now, I've switched to mock rest services to debug.

On returning a 428 HTTP Code (force a password change), I get a Webflow error.
I want to allow the password change to also be managed by a REST endpoint.

Do I need to add an action-state for handleauthenticationfailure with a bunch of transitions in my login-webflow.xml? Shouldn't CAS be doing this for me?

Exception (without any login-webflow.xml overlay):

```
WHO: casuser
WHAT: Supplied credentials: [casuser]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 12 10:20:39 CEST 2017
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================

>
2017-10-12 10:20:39,711 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/cas].[dispatcherServlet]] - <Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'handleAuthenticationFailure' of flow 'login'] with root cause>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find state with id 'casMustChangePassView' in flow 'login' -- Known state ids are 'array<String>['initialAuthenticationRequestValidationCheck', 'ticketGrantingTicketCheck', 'initializeLoginForm', 'viewLoginForm', 'realSubmit', 'showAuthenticationWarningMessages', 'sendTicketGrantingTicket', 'viewRedirectToUnauthorizedUrlView', 'viewServiceErrorView', 'redirectView', 'postView', 'headerView', 'viewGenericLoginSuccess', 'showWarningView', 'finalizeWarning', 'serviceUnauthorizedCheck', 'serviceCheck', 'warn', 'gatewayRequestCheck', 'hasServiceCheck', 'renewRequestCheck', 'generateServiceTicket', 'terminateSession', 'gatewayServicesManagementCheck', 'serviceAuthorizationCheck', 'redirect', 'handleAuthenticationFailure', 'casAuthenticationBlockedView', 'casBadWorkstationView', 'casBadHoursView', 'casAccountLockedView', 'casAccountDisabledView', 'casPasswordUpdateSuccess', 'passwordChangeAction', 'casExpiredPassView', 'casResetPasswordSendInstructionsView', 'sendInstructions', 'casResetPasswordSentInstructionsView']'
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.getStateInstance(Flow.java:342) ~[spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.DefaultTargetStateResolver.resolveTargetState(DefaultTargetStateResolver.java:60) ~[spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:218) ~[spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395) ~[spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) ~[spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.5.RELEASE]
```

As shown here on the mailing list,
https://www.mail-archive.com/cas-user@apereo.org/msg03913.html

I did at some point add this action-state and the corresponding end-state/view-state.

The page would load, but I would get the error telling me that the submit transition for this state was not found in the list of states, when I would submit the page.

I have only rudimentary knowledge of Spring.

My application.properties:

```
##
#This is a test comment
# CAS Server Context Configuration
#
server.context-path=/cas
server.port=8443

#server.ssl.key-store=file:/etc/cas/thekeystore
#server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
#server.ssl.key-password=changeit
# server.ssl.ciphers=
# server.ssl.client-auth=
# server.ssl.enabled=
# server.ssl.key-alias=
# server.ssl.key-store-provider=
# server.ssl.key-store-type=
# server.ssl.protocol=
# server.ssl.trust-store=
# server.ssl.trust-store-password=
# server.ssl.trust-store-provider=
# server.ssl.trust-store-type=

server.max-http-header-size=2097152
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.connection-timeout=20000
server.error.include-stacktrace=NEVER

server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2097152
server.tomcat.basedir=build/tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.max-threads=10
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port
server.tomcat.protocol-header=X-Forwarded-Proto
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-FORWARDED-FOR
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true

##
# CAS Cloud Bus Configuration
#
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false
# spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled=true
# spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled=true
# spring.cloud.bus.destination=CasCloudBus
# spring.cloud.bus.ack.enabled=true

endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.sensitive=true

endpoints.restart.enabled=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false

management.security.enabled=true
management.security.roles=ACTUATOR,ADMIN
management.security.sessions=if_required
management.context-path=/status
management.add-application-context-header=false

security.basic.authorize-mode=role
security.basic.enabled=false
security.basic.path=/cas/status/**

##
# CAS Web Application Session Configuration
#
server.session.timeout=300
server.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.session.tracking-modes=COOKIE

##
# CAS Thymeleaf View Configuration
#
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
##
# CAS Log4j Configuration
#
# logging.config=file:/etc/cas/log4j2.xml
server.context-parameters.isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled=true

##
# CAS AspectJ Configuration
#
spring.aop.auto=true
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true

cas.webflow.autoconfigure=true

##
# CAS Authentication Credentials
#
#cas.authn.accept.users=casuser::Mellon

cas.authn.rest.uri=http://demo5038781.mockable.io/test_cas
cas.authn.rest.passwordEncoder.type=NONE

cas.authn.pm.enabled=true
cas.authn.pm.reset.securityQuestionsEnabled=false

cas.authn.pm.rest.endpointUrlEmail=http://demo0014279.mockable.io/test_cas
cas.authn.pm.rest.endpointUrlChange=http://demo7912226.mockable.io/test_cas
```

My POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.kaso.itp</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verifyDownload>true</verifyDownload>
                    <checksumAlgorithm>MD5</checksumAlgorithm>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                    <archive>
                        <compress>false</compress>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp${app.server}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                        </manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cas</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-rest-authentication</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-pm</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-pm-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-pm-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <cas.version>5.2.0-RC3</cas.version>
        <springboot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <!-- app.server could be -jetty, -undertow, -tomcat, or blank if you plan 
            to provide appserver -->
        <app.server>-tomcat</app.server>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth-releases</id>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>pgp</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.s4u.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pgpverify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <pgpKeyServer>hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net</pgpKeyServer>
                            <pgpKeysCachePath>${settings.localRepository}/pgpkeys-cache</pgpKeysCachePath>
                            <scope>test</scope>
                            <verifyPomFiles>true</verifyPomFiles>
                            <failNoSignature>false</failNoSignature>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get a chance to review this?
https://github.com/apereo/cas/pull/2940

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!! So in a nutshell, this functionality was released as I posted (in v5.1.5)? I searched the interwebz a ton but missed the page for the pull request. Thanks for your help! You're awesome! 

Edit: v5.1.5 has much better code structure for the pm support classes. Kudos!

Comment: The PR is tagged for 5.2.0 RC4; I don't offhand remember if the change was backported to 5.1.x; it likely was. Try with 5.1.5 at this time and see if you notice the difference.